# See if org-mode heading is collapsed

Tags: org-mode

I just need a function that will say if a heading is collapsed or not.

Need it to ensure an open heading, because org-cycle, well, cycles and it appears there are no good alternatives (e.g. `org-show-entry` shows ellipsis instead of children).

Comment: Why not using `org-show-subtree` on the headline in question?

Comment: @Tobias org-show-subtree: `Show everything after this heading at deeper levels.` This would be OK, but I want the children collapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen a particular function that does this. What I have seen `org-mode` and `outline-mode` code use is the expression: `(outline-invisible-p (line-end-position))`. To tell if a heading is collapsed you can evaluate this expression when on a heading (you can check if you're on a heading with `org-at-heading-p`). If it returns t, then the heading is collapsed; otherwise it is not collapsed.

I'll explain a little bit about how it works. `outline-invisible-p` takes a point in the buffer as an argument returns `t` if the character after the point is invisible or not. When a heading is collapsed the point right after the heading (ie. the one after the end position of the line) will be invisible. So calling `outline-invisible-p` with `(line-end-position)` is an indicator of whether a heading is collapsed.

You could easily write a function to check for this. (In fact I would recommend doing this as opposed to using the expression because it's clearer what is being checked).

```
(defun +org-heading-collapsed-p ()
  "Return t if an current heading is collapsed."
  (outline-invisible-p (line-end-position)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an [outline command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Outline-Visibility.html) that shows only the next level children of the heading at point, which might have done what OP intended:

> C-c C-i: Make immediate subheadings (one level down) of the current heading line visible (outline-show-children)